# Scrambling code in android

Tags: android, gsm, telephony, cellular-network, umts

Can anyone tell me how to get the scrambling code  of serving cell in android?
I have tried [getPSC()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html#getPsc%28%29)  but it is always retrieving -1 . I am able to get [neighbour cell psc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/NeighboringCellInfo.html#getPsc%28%29) correctly but serving cell psc is always giving -1.

Comment: This is extremely vague, try adding more detail

Comment: be more specific on asking question

Comment: I think the question here is perfectly clear, but it's very technical, and you can only understand the question if you have sufficient knowledge of cell phone technologies and the Android API.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_pilot_channel for some more technical background.

Comment: I agree with Ken Bloom.  This question isn't vague, it's esoteric.

Comment: That said, it may be a dupe of a [couple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613736/getpsc-using-gsmcelllocation-in-android) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631870/how-to-getpsc-and-signal-strength-in-samsung-galaxy-ii-and-tab) questions that have been asked here before, but none of them have answers either.

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html#getPsc%28%29), you'll see that the scrambling code is only relevant to a UMTS network. If the cell network uses any other technology (e.g. GSM), you'll get -1 as the result.

Edit:

Another thought: maybe there's a bug and the hardware vendor didn't properly hook up the `getPsc()` call to do the right thing.